# How to unionize error types in Scala?

Tags: scala, error-handling

Suppose I have a few functions

```
val f1: Int => Error1 \/ Int = ??? // maybe should use Kleisli instead
val f2: Int => Error2 \/ Int = ???
val f3: Int => Error3 \/ Int = ???
```

... and I need to compose them:

```
val f123 = {a: Int =>  
  for(b <- f1(a); c <- f2(b); d <- f3(c)) yield d  // does not compile
}
```

`f123` should return `Error1 | Error2 | Error3 \/ Int` but I don't have `|` in Scala and hence I am using inheritance:

```
sealed trait Error123
object Error1 extends Error123
object Error2 extends Error123
object Error3 extends Error123

val f123: Int => Error123 \/ Int = ... // now it compiles
```

... but what if I need to compose `f1` and `f2` ?

Should I create a new trait `Error12` and make `Error1` and `Error2` extend it ? What if I have five functions `f1`, `f2`, ..., `f4`, `f5` and *five* error classes ?

I don't like this inheritance approach because it *changes* already existing types `Error1`, `Error2` et al just to define their unions. So I am wondering how to *unionize* these types in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is the best approach.  What are you trying to do? Define a function that may return either a result or an error of type `Error123`, what else it there to say?

By defining `Error123` as a sealed trait and extending it with N case classes better describing the error you make sure that the caller will have to handle all cases since the compiler will ask him to use an exhaustive pattern matching.

If it is that verbose and cumbersome maybe you need to rethink the ADT of your error cases.

Answer (score 0):

Scala has a monadic Try construction that probably delivers the functionality you are looking for, trading your own `Error` class by `Failure`.

Your monadic composition would become:

```
val f1: Int => Try[Int] = i => Success(i)  
val f2: Int => Try[Int] = i => Success(i*2)
val f3: Int => Try[Int] = i => if (i>4) Success(i+1) else Failure(new Exception("unsupported operation"))
```

... and then to compose them:

```
val f123 : Int => Try[Int] = {a: Int =>  
  for(b <- f1(a); c <- f2(b); d <- f3(c)) yield d
}
```

eg:

```
scala> f123 (2)
res2: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(6)

scala> f123 (1)
res4: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: unsupported operation)
```

Comment: This is a reasonable thing to do but it doesn't really answer the question. `Try` is essentially just a covariant `Throwable \/ ?`, and the OP could accomplish the same thing by having his error types extend `Throwable`.

Comment: @TravisBrown I get your point, but it's hard to guess what the bg of the question is. Either it's about union types, so the mention of 'error handling' is just as irrelevant as this answer or it's about error handling in general, and this question would be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option available to you is Bill Venners' [Scalactic](http://www.scalactic.org) library. It provides `Or` and `Every` constructs for functional error handling.